# CSS not loading in FF. Different than others issues

Tags: css, firefox, razor, stylesheet, loading

One of my stylesheets doesn't seem to load every style. I've read everything i can find but the issues that people usually have are obvious things to me but i can't seem to figure out my  own issue. I have a site made using Razor and this is where i call my stylesheets in the head section.

```
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/reset.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" />

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/searchLayout.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/searchSkin.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/skin.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/AvailabilityLayout.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/AvailabilitySkin.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen"/>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/Home.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The issue seems to be with the AVailabilitySkin.css and sometimes AvailabilityLayout.css. So for example i have this code in AvailibilitySkin.css:

```
    td#price h2, td#price h4
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

And it doesn't get picked up, I don't even see it being overwritten by another style or anything. But if I add the same code to the Skin.css file then it works perfectly fine. I can't add all my styles to Skin.css so i can't just put that style in there and call it a day. It has to be separated, right now the site is being developed locally so unfortunately i cannot post a link to the site but if anything is needed (like more code) please let me know. I haven't been able to find the issue and I've tried adding @charset "UTF-8"; at the top of the stylesheets and it didn't really do much.

Comment: probably a moot point, but firstly I would change your naming convention and avoid capitalisation. You say AVailabilitySkin, notice AV unlike the next issue stylesheet, Av etc. Remove capitalisation and try using
 td#price h2, td#price h4 {text-align:center !important;}
to see if you have got the right target and if so whether or not you are being superseded by another stylesheet.

Comment: You are doing html/css. You should try and stick with the standards... No capitalization, separate words by using `-`, so on and so forth... Also, do you have a (non-)working example to be looked at? You should look in your inspector to see whether the stylesheets have at least been loaded or not.

Comment: Any CSS-related errors in the console in Firefox?

Comment: I don't seem to find any CSS-related errors. I'm always on the inspector testing and editing things and the styles aren't being overwritten, they're not being loaded. @JonPaulH I've updated my naming conventions and the AV was actually just a typo i made here. I've tried !important but it doesn't work even though it works just fine in Chrome. These styles are being overlooked because part of the stylesheet does load so i'm not sure if this is a bug or what to do to force the page to load. Like i said if i copy/paste into skin.css it works so it should work the same in any other stylesheet.

Comment: Actually @BorisZbarsky, correction. There are errors in the firefox console but they're not for the styles that i need, they are mostly for some vendor specific styles. -moz-box-shadow and -moz-border-radius, and some parsing errors for some reason such as an error is parsing margin for a style written like this:
`#maxHeader
    {
        margin-left: -3px;
        padding: 10px 12px 10px 11px;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been fixed guys/gals. In the end it was just another mistake by me and it wasn't coming up in the Console and Visual Studio wasn't flagging it as an issue. It was mostly just a missed single quote and another programmer here ran the code through WebStorm and it came right up and fixed it. Thanks for the help and sorry for the dumb mistake question.